# "Too many" requests seem to break Oracle server

Tags: oracle, linux

We're using a vendor-provided (closed-source) software, which consists of multiple processes (not threads) on multiple computers performing the calculations.

The application is written to ask each "engine" to perform a certain part of the work -- and each such process is supposed to obtain the necessary details from the database directly. They all do that *all at once*, at the beginning of the batch...

After enlarging the number of servers recently -- and thus the number of processes -- we're observing the following strange behavior...

Although all 1400 processes launch correctly and login to Oracle (we had to raise the limit on logins for that first), when we attempt to start a computing batch, about 20% of them *die*.

Before dying, they all complain of `ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred`. The deaths seem evenly distributed across all servers.

The remaining 1100-1200 processes finish their portions of the calculations properly...

It seems like Oracle -- despite its VM having 256Gb of RAM and 16 cores at its disposal -- is unable to handle the sudden load-spike. Is there some other parameter -- database or the OS -- we can tune up to improve things?

The server is running 19c Enterprise Edition on RedHat version 7. The application is written in C and C++, using client version 12.

*Update*: one of the suggestions in comments was to set the `SQLNET.{RECV,SEND}_TIMEOUT` figures higher than their normal defaults -- but those are the server-side parameters, which I cannot modify.

Reading the [vendor documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETRF/sqlnet.htm#NETRF417), however, I gathered that the `TCP.CONNECT_TIMEOUT` is the knob to turn on the client. So I created the new `sqlnet.ora` with the following two lines:

```
tcp.connect_timeout=811
sqlnet.outbound_connect_timeout=809
```

Unfortunately, this didn't seem to help...

Moreover, the processes quit -- due to the ORA-12170 error -- much earlier than the specified timeouts would suggest: in 3-4 minutes instead of the 800+ seconds...

Comment: There are a couple of things that could be going on that occur to me: first, how is overall memory usage on the database server when the apparent connection limit is reached? Second, how many network interfaces does the server have? Is the OS complaining of any network resource issues?

Comment: There is only one network interface (plus the `lo`), `free` lists 139Gb of RAM as "available", and there is nothing alarming in the output of `dmesg`.

Comment: Something doesn't add up. "Connect timeout occurred" suggests that some application instances cannot connect, and yet you say that all 1400 of them "login to Oracle"; did you actually verify that you have 1400 open sessions? Is there a possibility to stagger the application instance connects, to distribute them over several seconds?

Comment: The processes all _login_ to Oracle at startup -- successfully -- and then sit idle awaiting start of the calculations. When the calculations begin, they all start _querying_ -- and that's when about 20% of them die...

Yes, staggering would've been the first thing I attempted, but the application is closed-source...

Comment: There's almost certainly some kind of network bottleneck. Have you tried adjusting the sqlnet.ora parameters `SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT` or `SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT`, on the server for sure but also on the clients if they're using Oracle Client and not JDBC?

Comment: No, @pmdba, I haven't tried that... The Oracle server is out of my reach -- although I could ask the DBAs to try this or that. I do control the client-side, where is `sqlnet.ora`? Is it in the same directory as `tnsnames.ora` (determined by `$TNS_ADMIN`)?

Comment: Yes, it would be in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks, @pmdba, we don't have the `sqlnet.ora` on the client-side right now at all, so, I presume, the client uses whatever the defaults are. I can create such file anew -- what lines would you suggest?